# (in c) Get a float number from user. Change positions before "." and after "." For example: ab.cd should be cd.ab

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

float a,c,d;
int b;  

printf("Enter the float number: "); scanf("%f", &a);

    a * 100 == b ;
    b % 100 == c ;
    c + a == d ;

printf("%f", d);
}
```

It prints 0.00.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Have you ever written any C code before? No offense but this is plain wrong code.

Comment: enable compiler warnings.....

Comment: `==` is a _comparison_ operator, not an assignment one. In other words, you've never assigned any value to your variables.

Comment: Please read literally *any* introductory C tutorial before writing C code. You seem to lack a basic understanding of C syntax.

Comment: @cad I'm first class in university and i'm starting to learning code, 4 weeks     ago i dont even know a thing about c, or any program language

Comment: Oh really? This site's only purpose is humiliating people or helping people? You guys can give any answer but humiliating..

Comment: @Kanbak I agree this is not the most kind community, but your question is too basic. Nobody is trying to humiliate you. You should start reading some introductory books to C ( Is not an easy language, and it can be harder if you know nothing about programming), learn how to use a debugger, once you know how to use it's the most powerful tool you could learn. This kind of excercise is pretty standard in every book, so you should be able to solve it if you read a couple of chapters from any tutorial

Comment: No one is trying to humiliate you. People just get irritated when people come along asking really basic questions which show no effort on the part of the asker to research the issue (or the language!)

Comment: Invest in K&R second edition... read it and learn from it, before posting questions where no research/effort on your part is shown. Also, look at [faq] to see what would be expected of posters like you.

Answer (score 0):

These statements:

```
a * 100 == b ;
b % 100 == c ;
c + a == d ;
```

are a series of comparisons. `==` is the equality comparison operator, while `=` is the assignment operator. Also, `%` is the modulus operator, and can only be used for integral operands. Perhaps you meant something more like

```
b = (float) ((int) (a * 100) % 100); /* fraction */
c = (float) ((int) a % 100) / 100.0; /* mantissa */
d = b + c;
```

Note that this is not necessarily good style, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

To start with `==` is a comparison operator. To assign a value, you need to use `=`.
Assignment syntax in C is written as:

```
b = a * 100;
```

Try reading some tutorials on assignment operations and you should see where you are going wrong.
[Here's one to get you started.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arithmetic_operators.htm)